# Traefik 2.1 does not forward request

Tags: docker, docker-compose, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm would like to use Traefik as load balancer for the backend, which is listening on port `2500`. There should be two backend containers that handle requests on port `80`. The Traefik dashboard should be available on port `8080`. I also want the backend containers to automatically restart when they've crashed.

When I run the `docker-compose` file below with `docker-compose --compatibility up --build`, I can access both backends on localhost `2500` and `2501`. However, the backends should only be available through Traefik on port `80`. Unfortunately, I can't access the backend on port `80`. Thanks for your help.

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  backend:
    deploy:
        replicas: 2
    build: .
    ports:
      - "2500-2501:2500"
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: curl http://127.0.0.1:2500 -s -f -o /dev/null || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

The exposed ports are removed from backend service. Added backend router working on 127.0.0.1:80 --> 127.0.0.1:2500 .  Also exposed 2500 port for traefik.

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  backend:
    deploy:
        replicas: 2
    build: .
    #############################################################################
    #ports:
    #  - "2500-2501:2500"
    #############################################################################
    labels:
        traefik.enable: true
        traefik.http.routers.backend.rule: Host(`127.0.0.1`)
        traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints: web
        traefik.http.services.backend_service.loadbalancer.server.port: 2500
    #############################################################################        
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: curl http://127.0.0.1:2500 -s -f -o /dev/null || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    #############################################################################
      - 2500:2500
    #############################################################################
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```